# Setting Icon for electron-packager

Tags: electron

I am trying to package an electron app using electron-packager. I am using the following statement in package.json :

```
"build": "electron-packager . MyApp --platform=linux --arch=x64 --overwrite --icon= path/to/icon.png"
```

But I still can't see the icon. I am using ubuntu 14.04!

Comment: Did you install wine?

Comment: No , I dont have wine .... Is that necessary ?

Comment: actually for ubuntu build it is not

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#icon -> have to be set in BrowserWindow and setting the icon in the file manager is not currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux the icon must be set in the BrowserWindow according to the electron-packager documentation

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#icon

> Linux: this option is not required, as the dock/window list icon is set via the icon option in the BrowserWindow constructor. Please note that you need to use a PNG, and not the OS X or Windows icon formats, in order for it to show up in the dock/window list. Setting the icon in the file manager is not currently supported.

The relevant section of the BrowserWindow API documentation is here http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#new-browserwindowoptions

The code to add the icon would look something like:

```
let window = new BrowserWindow({
    icon: "path/to/icon.png"
});
```